# Retrieving the ID of the column and storing it in Session when clicked on Hyperlinkfield

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `gridview` populated by an SQL table which has two fields: **`ID`** and **`Subjects`**.

**`Subject`** is on the form of `HyperLinkField`. I would like to store the `ID` of the column in a session so, when I click the `HyperLinkField` to be able to use it on the another WebForm. I have used **`DataBound`** but it just doesn't seem to work. I am using C#.

Thank you in advance.

P.S: This is my first question, sorry for the inconvenience. I am a beginner in programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Button field of Link type in your Grid View and set DataTextField to your Subject which you wanted to display. Then handle RowCommand event of the grid view and you can easily get the ID and assign it to session variables.

```
<asp:GridView OnRowCommand="grid1_RowCommand" runat="server" ID="grid1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Link" DataTextField="Subject" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

And Code behind :

```
protected void grid1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
       int rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
       string str = grid1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[0].Text;
       Session["Subject"] = str;
    }
```